# Which one is faster for touch sensing out of touchesNNNN:withEvent: and UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have developed a pretty complex code fully on touchesNNNN:withEvent: methods (where NNNN stands for Began, Moves, Ended or Cancelled), however, I am facing a bit of a lag in the processing. Its not much of a lag but I, as a developer still feel it. So, now I am looking forward to move the code to be handled by UIPanGestureRecognizer.

My question is will the UIPanGestureRecognizer be worth it ? I have a lot of drawing implementation on touches in my code like where a user touches, drags and draws a line + some heavy logic detecting the pattern of drawing and informing the user in real-time if he makes a mistake or any gesture.

Has anyone seen any performance benefit of UIPanGestureRecognizer over touchesNNNN:withEvent: methods ? Because I am not aware if these gestureRecognizers are further optimised to receive input from hardware level or something..

Any help and experience notes from you guys with help me take a proper decision and save my time. :)

Comment: All the gestures implements the `touches:` method in their classes. So `touches:` method provide the core element to the `gestures`

Answer (score 0):

Any view that handles touch events is actually working with `touchesDidBegin:withEvent` (etc.). Logically, when adding a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to your view, you are implicitly adding the touches handling logic to your view, basically, you're implementing the `touchesDid...` outside of your view and layering it on top of it. If you'd like to improve your performance with the detection of patterns try using `gcd` and threading.

Comment: If I push the code in touhesMoved:withEvent: into some other thread then I'm afraid I will still have to wait for the thread to complete in order to get the results and proceed ahead. Which will make matters worse don't you think so ?

Comment: If you necessarily have to wait then yeah